# NSMutableArray multidimensional, get a column

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

i have a NSArray created with a Dictionary:

```
aMapData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sizeof(jsonResponse)];


for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in jsonResponse) {  

    NSDictionary *row = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[dict objectForKey:@"pID"], @"pID", [dict objectForKey:@"Address"], @"Address",  nil];
    [aMapData addObject:row];

  }
```

It has about 100 rows.

I want to get the pID column, is the only option the iteration and:

```
 [aMapData objectAtIndex:0]
```

?

Thank you in advance!

I found it, is not necessary an array:

```
NSArray *idPath = [aMapData valueForKey:@"pID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Otherwise you have to store each column in a separate array.

```
pID = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
address = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSMutableDictionary *dict in jsonResponse) {  
    [pID addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"pID"]];
    [address addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"address"]];
}
```